# Spring validation: getting "Invalid target for Validator" when using two validators

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, custom-validators

I'm having issues implementing two validators using @InitBinder annotation.

Controller code:

```
@Autowired
private SessionValidator sessionValidator;

@Autowired
private ChannelValidator channelValidator;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.addValidators(sessionValidator, channelValidator);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public UserInfo findBySession(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute Session session,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute Channel channel){
    //...
}
```

Session validator:

```
@Component
public class SessionValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass){
        return Session.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors){
        //...
    }
}
```

Channel validator:

```
@Component
public class ChannelValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass){
        return Channel.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors){
        //...
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the following exception when calling the controller:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid target for Validator [com.almundo.p13n.dna.validators.ChannelValidator@4e642ee1]: Session(null, null)
```

Anyone knows how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You binds two validators  but for each parameter to validate only one of them will be supported.
`SessionValidator` support the `Session` parameter but doesn't support the `Channel` parameter and reversely `ChannelValidator` supports the `Channel` parameter but doesn't support  the `Session` parameter.
Whereas the exception.

As first alternative you could support both parameter types in each Spring Validator subclass.   It is a little clumsy but it should work :

```
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass){
    return Channel.class.equals(aClass) ||  Session.class.equals(aClass);
}
```

You should of course check the type in `validate()` and perform the validation only if it matched with the validator class.

As second alternative, use the standard validation API by implementing `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` for each class to validate and by validating the parameters explicitly in the controller.

As third alternative, if it makes sense you could annotate directly the constraints on the `Session` and the `Channel` classes.  So, you could still use  `@Valid` in the parameter declaration to keep the automate validation.

Comment: Spring should use a smarter approach! I don't understand the purpose of checking the type in supports(Class aClass) method (it's not being used for match the proper validator) or adding several validators in binder (when only one should work).

Comment: First approach looks clumsy, as you said, and second and third approach are impossible when you can't modify Session or Channel classes :(

Comment: The second way doesn't require to modify Session and Channel. You would have two classes that implement `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` that specify how to validate them and you will explicitly invoke in your controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can add only supported validators:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    if (binder.getTarget() == null) return;
    final ImmutableList<Validator> validatorsList = ImmutableList.of(
        new CunsomValidator1(),
        new CunsomValidator2()
    );

    for (Validator validator : validatorsList) {
        if (validator.supports(binder.getTarget().getClass())) {
            binder.addValidators(validator);
        }
    }
}
```